# I am getting the issue in SELF JOIN in MYSQL query. Please check the table and query

Tags: mysql, self-join

Please create the table by below query:

```
 CREATE TABLE `trade` 
      ( 
         `order`      VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL, 
         `positionid` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
         `time`       DATETIME DEFAULT NULL, 
         `volume`     FLOAT NOT NULL 
      ) 
    engine=innodb 
    DEFAULT charset=latin1;
```

Insert query

```
 INSERT INTO `trade` 
                (`order`, 
                 `positionid`, 
                 `time`, 
                 `volume`) 
    VALUES      ('42556', 
                 1111, 
                 '2018-08-15 07:27:44', 
                 2), 
                ('42560', 
                 1111, 
                 '2018-08-18 08:32:47', 
                 2), 
                ('42564', 
                 1235, 
                 '2018-08-21 07:10:12', 
                 5), 
                ('42572', 
                 1235, 
                 '2018-08-23 17:20:26', 
                 2), 
                ('42580', 
                 1235, 
                 '2018-08-23 17:03:30', 
                 3);
```

I have tried below query:

```
 SELECT b.`order` AS `TICKET`, 
           b.`time`  AS `OPEN_TIME`, 
           j.`time`  AS `CLOSE_TIME` 
    FROM   trade AS b 
           LEFT JOIN trade AS j 
                  ON b.`positionid` = j.`positionid` 
    WHERE  b.`time` != j.`time`;
```

**Table :**

[image]

**Error output :**

This image shows repetitive data:

[image]

**Required Output:**

This image will shows the required output :

[image]

**Description :**

When we open trade, it will stored to trade table. After that when we will  close the trade, it will do another entry with different time and volume( If trade will close partially then volume will be different otherwise close fully trade). 
Here first entry will OPEN_TIME which stored as Time and second will CLOSE_TIME. So how to convert two or more records into single record with OPEN_TIME and CLOSE_TIME?

Comment: I don't see where you calculate that Volume column. Looks like you need a GROUP BY with COUNT somewhere in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this

```
SELECT j.`order` AS `TICKET`, 
b.`positionid` AS `PositionID`,
   b.`time`  AS `OPEN_TIME`, 
   j.`time`  AS `CLOSE_TIME` ,
   j.`volume` AS `Volume`
FROM   trade AS b 
   INNER JOIN trade AS j 
          ON b.`positionid` = j.`positionid` 
where b.time = (select min(time) from trade as c1 where b.positionid=c1.positionid)
AND b.time!=j.time;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the time condition to:

**--Edit**

```
where j.time = (select max(time) from test_query where positionid = j.positionid) 
and b.time = (select min(time) from test_query where positionid = b.positionid)
```

so that `b` instance becomes equivalent for opening orders and `j` becomes instance for closing orders

Comment: Thanks @codeLover for answer. But here this condition not working for partially closed trades. See the required output  and actual table when positionid same for more than two records.

Comment: Please check the condition now

Comment: Thanks again for reply. But its skipping ther order 42580.

Comment: Can you have a look at your data once, because if it is working for other two orders, it should work for this one too..